# ASP.NET Update datalist by timer is not working

Tags: asp.net, timer, datalist

I have an `updatepanel` with a `label` and a `datalist` inside as follows

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">     
  <ContentTemplate>    
      <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="2000" Enabled="True" ontick="Timer1_Tick"></asp:Timer>
      Tick <asp:Label ID="LabelTick" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
      <asp:DataList ID="dl1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" RepeatColumns = "4" CellSpacing = "3" RepeatLayout = "Table">
         <ItemTemplate>
            ...
         </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:DataList>
      <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT ..."></asp:SqlDataSource> 
   </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

In the code-behind I update the databind after every tick:

```
Protected Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

    dl1.DataSourceID = SqlDataSource1.ID
    dl1.DataBind()

    LabelTick.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString()

End Sub
```

The `label` is updated correctly every 2 seconds, which means the timer runs correctly. But the `DataList` is not refreshed, it is only refreshed once after page load.
Why?

Comment: It should re-fresh. However, with a update panel, the refresh will occur rather smooth, and you not see a change unless in fact the data has or is changing. When you run the timer event, does the data persist, or continue to display? In other words, how do you determine that the data is not refreshing?

Comment: Also remove the setting for the data list, and simply try a databind event for the data source control. Eg: Sqldatasource.DataBind(). that should re-load

Comment: when I remove rows from the table directly in the database, the data list should reflect this change. But it doesn't. Thats how I determine that the data is not refreshing. The Sqldatasource.DataBind() had no impact :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of the tick call:

```
 UpdatePanel1.Update()
```

Comment: This had no impact (

Comment: Actually, I found out that my SQLDataSource must be INSIDE the updatepanel. Now it works. Thanks.
Btw, I have to add, if the UpdatePanel.Update() function is used, the update panel must be set to "Update = Conditional".